# Training a decision tree using id3 algorithm by sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.5, decision-tree, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I am trying to train a decision tree using the id3 algorithm.
The purpose is to get the indexes of the chosen features, to esimate the occurancy, and to build a total confusion matrix.

The algorithm should split the dataset to training set, and a test set, and use cross validation with 4 folds.

I am new to the subject, I've read the tutorials on sklearn and theory about learning process, but I'm still very confused.

What I've tried doing:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict,KFold,cross_val_score, 
train_test_split, learning_curve
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
results = cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=4)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
y_pred = cross_val_predict(estimator=clf, X=x, y=y, cv=4)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y,y_pred)
print(conf_mat)
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file='tree.dot')
```

I have some questions:

1. How can I get a list of the feature indexes used in the training? Do I have to go through the tree in clf? Couldn't find any api method to retrieve them.
2. Do I have to use 'fit', 'cross_val_score', and 'cross_val_predict'? It seems that all of them do some kind of learning process, but I could't manage to get the clf fitted, the accurancy and the confusuin matrix from one of them only.
3. Do I have to use the test set for the estimation or the partitions of the folds of the dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To retrieve the list of the features used in the training process you can just get the columns from the x in this way:

   `feature_list = x.columns`

   As you can know, not every feature can be useful in prediction. You can see this, after training the model, using

   `clf.feature_importances_`

   The index of a feature in the feature_list is the same as in the feature_importances list.
2. If you use cross validation, retrieving the scores can not be immediate.
   cross_val_score made the deal but a better way to have the scores could be using cross_validate. It works in the same way as cross_val_score, but you can retrieve more scores values just creating every score you need with make_score and passing it, here an example:

   ```
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,  cross_validate
   from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, make_scorer, recall_score 
   import pandas as pd, numpy as np       

   x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
   dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
   dtc_fit = dtc.fit(x_train, y_train)

   def tn(y_true, y_pred): return confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0, 0]
   def fp(y_true, y_pred): return confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0, 1]
   def fn(y_true, y_pred): return confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[1, 0]
   def tp(y_true, y_pred): return confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[1, 1]

   scoring = {
       'tp' : make_scorer(tp), 
       'tn' : make_scorer(tn), 
       'fp' : make_scorer(fp), 
       'fn' : make_scorer(fn), 
       'accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score),
       'precision': make_scorer(precision_score),
       'f1_score' : make_scorer(f1_score),
       'recall'   : make_scorer(recall_score)
   }

   sc = cross_validate(dtc_fit, x_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring=scoring)

   print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (sc['test_accuracy'].mean(), sc['test_accuracy'].std() * 2))
   print("Precision: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (sc['test_precision'].mean(), sc['test_precision'].std() * 2))
   print("f1_score: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (sc['test_f1_score'].mean(), sc['test_f1_score'].std() * 2))
   print("Recall: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (sc['test_recall'].mean(), sc['test_recall'].std() * 2), "\n")

   stp = math.ceil(sc['test_tp'].mean())
   stn = math.ceil(sc['test_tn'].mean())
   sfp = math.ceil(sc['test_fp'].mean())
   sfn = math.ceil(sc['test_fn'].mean())

   confusion_matrix = pd.DataFrame(
       [[stn, sfp], [sfn, stp]],
       columns=['Predicted 0', 'Predicted 1'],
       index=['True 0', 'True 1']
   )
   print(conf_m)
   ```
3. When you use the cross_val functions, the function itself create the folds for the test and the training. If you want to manage the train fold and the test fold you can do it by yourself using the K_Fold class.
   If you need to keep the class balancement, always need for a good scoring by a DecisionTreeClassifier, you have to use StratifiedKFold. If you want to shuffle randomly the values contained in the folds, you can use StratifiedShuffleSplit. Here an example:

   ```
   from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
   from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
   from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, make_scorer, recall_score
   import pandas as pd, numpy as np

   precision = []; recall = []; f1score = []; accuracy = []

   sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.2)    
   dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()

   for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
       X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
       y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

       dtc.fit(X_train, y_train)
       pred = dtc.predict(X_test)

       precision.append(precision_score(y_test, pred))
       recall.append(recall_score(y_test, pred))
       f1score.append(f1_score(y_test, pred))
       accuracy.append(accuracy_score(y_test, pred))   

   print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (np.mean(accuracy),np.std(accuracy) * 2))
   print("Precision: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (np.mean(precision),np.std(precision) * 2))
   print("f1_score: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (np.mean(f1score),np.std(f1score) * 2))
   print("Recall: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (np.mean(recall),np.std(recall) * 2))
   ```

I hope I've answered everything you needed!

Comment: Thank you so much!
1. I meant to get the chosen features in the result, So I assume I can use the feature_importances_ for that? 
2. If I use the "accurancy" parameter for scoring, how does it changes the algorithm? Don't I have to supply a scoring function that implements the gainInfo using entropy there to make it 'id3'?
3. Doesnt the cross_validate keeps the class balancement?

Comment: 1. Yes, you're right. Just watching feature_importances_ you can choose the features most important in the prediction in order to reduce the complexity of your prediction model (this step is also called **feature selection**)  
2. When you evaluate a model, you don't just use the accuracy but precision, recall and other scores too. This scores can change your feature selection process    
3. cross_validate support the class balacement. Using the solution that I've posted allows you to retrive your own confusion matrix too. Shortly, I've shown your how cross_validate works in this point

Comment: Did you use pandas as pd? I get an error "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'"

Comment: It helped a lot thank you, one more question - You have said that precision, recall and other scores are relevant for the learning process, why are they picked after the fitting then? Are they still relevant for id3 specifically?

Comment: Yes, I use pandas as pd, sorry I forgot to include it. Anyway, precision, recall and the other scores are measured after the validation step. These are relevant in every prediction model, such as ID3. Some models, like DecitionTree, are subject to Overfitting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). A model with a precision of 0.99 is probably overfitted. You can see these kind of things just observing the scores